# Facilitating anonymous feedback with possibility of dialogue

Tags: teaching, feedback, technology

I'd like to give students a platform to anonymously provide feedback on my course/teaching, but I'd like the platform to allow me to respond to individual students without revealing their identities. In the past, I've sent out anonymous surveys via Google Forms, and although its nice to hear students' perspectives, at times I would like to respond to a particular comment (for a variety of reasons - expressing gratitude for their feedback, sympathizing with their perspective, pointing them to a resource, further explaining the choices I make as a teacher, etc.). Google Forms of course doesn't allow me to respond to particular students.

Does anyone know of a platform that can facilitate some sort of chat-based dialogue between individual students and me in such a way that the students can remain anonymous?

Comment: I can't say exactly why, but this doesn't feel like a good idea.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: Thanks for your word of caution. I'm certainly aware of some undesirable outcomes here, but feel that if handled well the benefits of such dialogues with my students (overall) could outweigh any potential downfalls. Of course, I could be wrong and after trying it out can report back to confirm your suspicions!

Comment: I'd like to offer some perspective, especially from that of an undergrad student - they already receive multiple emails and reminders from their Univ system to complete instructor feedback, for each of the 4-5 courses they take per semester (in the US context). Most students might see these as chores to get done with. On top of this, a separate google survey form seems extra. Additionally, on top of this, to require them to further engage in a chat-based dialogue certainly seems too much on the part of the student.

Comment: @NebUzer: Thanks for your perspective. I myself am not much of a survey taker, so I usually ignore calls for feedback and for this reason I very much respect others who have no interest giving their time to fill out a form. Any feedback mechanism I implement is always optional (in fact, given that it is anonymous I'm not sure how I could require it without knowing who is doing it). Usually, only about 10-20% of my students will fill out a Google Form, but I still find the exercise valuable. I'm only looking to provide a platform for dialogue should a student want to engage in that way.